# can't see emojis on the chat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    if (data.labels.length && data.datasets.length) {
                return data.labels.map((label: any, i: number) => {
                  const meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
                  const style = meta.controller.getStyle(i);

                  return {
                    text: this.moods[i].emoji,
                    font: {
                      family: "'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol'",
                      size: 16,
                    },
                    fillStyle: style.backgroundColor,
                    strokeStyle: style.borderColor,
                    lineWidth: style.borderWidth,
                    hidden: isNaN(data.datasets[0].data[i]) || meta.data[i].hidden,
                    index: i,
                  };
                });
              }
              return [];
            },
          },
        }
```

can't see emojis on the chart
Using this code trying to see emojis on the chart. it is not visible[chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdHUw.png)